# how to remove browser's title and add my title dynamically in middle of titlebar

Tags: javascript, titlebar

here I m trying to set title of my website dynamically using javascript,  but how to set it in middle of title-bar , and how to remove -Mozilla FireFox / Google Chrome Text which is in end of title.. Is it possible?

```
 document.title = " Its " + Data;
```

one more thing..

i added favicon to my website,

```
<link rel="image_src" id="favicon" href="http://AAAAAA.com/logo.png" />
```

its works perfactly , but for my other page which is popout from main page.. 
its not working, i mean it is not displaying any logo/img..

Also try below function but not work for popout window.....

```
(function() {
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.type = 'image/x-icon';
link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
link.href = 'http://www.AAAAAA.com/logo.png';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}());
```

what should be wrong with pop out window...!!!

Comment: Try to ask only one question per post.

Comment: "in middle of titlebar with logo" ? what do you mean ?

Comment: A logo(favicon) in Left Corner of title bar.. and title text which i want in middle of titlebar